# Spring expressions and nullable values

Tags: c#, .net, spring.net

I use Spring.Core dll with 
[ExpressionEvaluator](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html) .

My simple code:

```
public void ComputedFields()
{
  var finance = new Finance();
  ExpressionEvaluator
    .SetValue(
      finance, 
      "FieldToBeSet", 
      ExpressionEvaluator
        .GetValue(
          finance, 
          "SomeNullableFinanceField.GetValueOrDefault(1)"));

  Assert.AreEqual(finance.FieldToBeSet, 1);
}
```

raises the following exception:

> Method `GetValueOrDefault` with the specified number and types of arguments does not exist.

`Finance` is a simple poco the `SomeNullableFinanceField` field is of type `decimal?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring.net ExpressionEvaluator doesn't know about .net Nullable types, so it doesn't try to find and invoke GetValueOrDefault method because of SomeNullableFinanceField is null.

If SomeNullableFinanceField is not null, it tries to invoke GetValueOrDefault on SomeNullableFinanceField value (decimal).

You should modify you expression:

```
ExpressionEvaluator
    .GetValue(
      finance, 
      "SomeNullableFinanceField != null ? SomeNullableFinanceField : 1");
```

or

```
ExpressionEvaluator
    .GetValue(
      finance, 
      "{SomeNullableFinanceField, 1}.nonNull()[0]");
```